# jQuery/Javascript if contains else do nothing

Tags: jquery

This function below adds the name of the student as a link to a div called 'output' when a button is pressed.

```
function getFavourite()
{
{
 name = 'Student 1 '
  $('#output').html('<a href=' + window.location.href + '?student=' + '>' + name + '</a>'+ ', ' + ($("#output").html()));
}


saveFavourites();
loadFavourites();
$("#favourites").show();
}
```

I'm trying to create more functionality where if the student's name is already in the div then when then the button is pressed the name is not added again and display an alert notifying the user.

```
function getFavourite()
{
if ($( "#output:not:contains('Student 1, ')" ))
    {(name = 'Student 1 ')
  $('#output').html('<a href=' + window.location.href + '?student=' + '>' + name +    a>'+ ', ' + ($("#output").html()));
        $("#favourites").show();
    }
else
{return null + alert("Already added to favourites")}


saveFavourites();
loadFavourites();

}
```

I've tried a lot of variations of the code above but with no luck.
thanks.

Comment: When you are writing the HTML couldn't you provide the anchor with the name of the student as the ID then check if any of the anchors have that ID when you try to add a new one?

Comment: `$( "#output:not(:contains('Student 1, ')" ))` will return a jQuery object which will always be true

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by checking its length, for example:

```
if ($("#container:contains('Test')").length > 0) {
    alert("It does contain");
} else {
    alert("It does not contain");
}
```

See [jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wE4k6/)

Comment: Thanks for your responce, it has helped me.

Comment: {if ($("#output:contains('Student 1')").length > 0) {
            + alert("Already added to favourites")
    }  what could I put in front of the alert so that it doesn't add anything at all to the div

Comment: I think you mean to check if there is not #output with 'Student 1' in it, then just use this: `if ($("#output:contains('Student 1')").length == 0) { alert("Not found"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Use a[href*="string"] selector, here a little fiddel http://jsfiddle.net/6KuP4/3/

html

```
<a href="url?student=Student 1">test</a>
<a href="url?student=Student 2">test</a>
```

css

```
a {
    display:block;
 }
 a[href*="Student 1"] {
  color: #1f6053; /* Student 1 is green */
 }
```

So in your jquery you can check in your statment that selector (probably Student 1 will replaced with a variable)

Js

```
 $( '#output > a[href*="' + name + '"]' )
```

Here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/686xA/26/

If you need to check only the last part or your url, try with a[href$="+ name +"] (fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jSb3P/4/)